# Apache Couch DB Error in Pushing File

Tags: database, file, couchdb

so im trying to push a file and this is what i get

Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:couchconfdemo-master 2 Parekh$ couchapp push . http........

Then it loads for a bit

Rahuls-MacBook-Pro:couchconfdemo-master 2 Parekh$

THIS KEEPS ON REAPEATING WHY?? Answers ASAP and thanks heres a link to the file

https://github.com/mheadd/couchconfdemo
and this is the website im trying to follow
http://blog.tropo.com/2012/02/08/sms-voting-app-in-10-minutes-with-tropo-and-couchdb/comment-page-1/#comment-24967
Thanks